# In django, __init__ function on Model, causes attribute error, cannot save to database

Tags: django

I am using django and a model definition such as

```
class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    order = models.IntegerField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.title = kwargs.get('title','Default Title')
        self.description = kwargs.get('description', 'DefDescription')
        self.order = kwargs.get('order', 0)
```

Attempting to call save() on an object of the question class, causes the shell to respond with

```
/django/db/utils.py", line 133, in _route_db
    return hints['instance']._state.db or DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS
AttributeError: 'Question' object has no attribute '_state'
```

However, removing the _____init_____ function, makes everything ok again. Any idea on what causes this and how to resolve it?

many thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to call the superclass' `__init__` method at some point in your subclass' `__init__` method:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Question, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # your code here
```

Comment: Something people should be aware of that hung me up is that super needs to be called before any assigning any fields to the model. It also appears that it unnecessary to save the model after assigning fields

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Django models docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects), it's not recommended to overwrite `__init__` method for models. Using `@classmethod` or custom manager is preferred.